# Is “women” a useful tag? (Nope, it’s been burninated)

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I noticed a recent question with the tag [women](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/women) which has no description and only 15 questions. They are questions involving women, but not really about women. The questions might be better tagged with something more descriptive of the issue, like [gender](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gender) or [discrimination](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discrimination).

If [women](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/women) is useful in some way I’ve overlooked, let’s fill in the tag wiki for it.

Answer (score 19):

Honestly I didn't even know we had one! Looking at the questions tagged with it I can't really see the need for it personally.

I'll hang back a bit and let others weigh in but I wouldn't see any problem with burninating it.

Comment: I'm with Burninating as well... very few questions with it and totally should have another tag like gender, etc.

Comment: Strike three. I've removed/replaced it on a few questions already. Recommend we just slowly remove it until it's cleaned up. We could consider putting a synonym in to gender to avoid it being recreated.

Comment: @Lilienthal good suggestion, I went and added such synonym (along with "men" to have balance)

Comment: Knew I forgot something. :) Thanks @DarkCygnus! Question can now be fully considered resolved.