# Bumping super-old threads

Tags: discussion

I've been noticing over the last couple  of days that a bunch of super old threads (4-5 years old) have been getting bumped to the top of the forum.  Can we not do that?  Makes it hard to know which questions need attention; answering a 4-5 year old question because you  didn't notice  the post-date in small, grey-on-white font,  is kind of awkward.

Comment: If you can provide a better answer than all of the existing answers to a question, why would that be awkward? It's actually pretty valuable in my opinion to put fresh eyes on old questions. I just put a bounty on an older question that attracted (in my opinion) an answer that was far superior to the existing ones when it got some attention after being bumped. Some older questions might need updating - things change and what might have made sense pre-pandemic doesn't make sense today.

Comment: It's unlikely that someone who asked a question 5 years ago still cares about the answer to such a question.

Comment: If you think our purpose here is to answer questions for each individual, you must have missed some parts of the [tour]. *With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about the workplace.* If the question is on-topic, it is something more than one person cares about.

Comment: You could use the [questions](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions) page as your default rather than the Home if you're looking for questions that need attention (sorted to newest obviously). Been doing that for about as long as I've used the site. We have a few tag cleanup posts on meta right now which will up the numbers, but you're *always* going to see old questions bumped because of people reaching the site through a web search.

Answer (score 9):

We can't really control whether a question is going to get bumped or not - if any of the events listed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-a-question-to-be-bumped) happens it's going to get a bump to the top of the Active list.

Sometimes this isn't desirable - and it's why things like [cleaning up old tags](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6949/is-women-a-useful-tag) can be done a few questions at a time to stop the the homepage getting flooded.

If avoiding these older questions is the goal a workaround is to browse by new - by going to https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions rather than the home page and making sure "Newest" is selected as the sort order (it's the default IIRC)